# python3 не видит свои пакеты

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

Есть проект, написанный в PyCharm на python, состоящий из нескольких каталогов, в каждом из которых есть несколько файлов с кодом.
В main.py импортируются эти файлы с кодом, как библиотеки, иногда полностью, иногда частично. При запуске из самого PyCharm всё работает без проблем, но при попытке запуска из терминала всякий раз случается ошибка импорта своих пакетов, при то, что они лежат в одном и том же каталоге.
Пробовал`python3 main.py` и `python3 ./main.py`. Пробовал и подниматься на каталог выше, пошагово, вплоть до корневого всё та же ситуация.
в самом файле main.py импорт прописан следующим образом:

```
import catalog_name.module_name
from catalog_name.module_name import something_name
```

т.е. весь импорт прописан относительно корня каталога проекта.

Comment: Судя по `python3` Вы пытаетесь запуститься на Linux. Если это так то `export PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/project/root`

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо.